# Is "position" a reserved word in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here's a simplified version of my code that compiles:

```
#include <iostream>

class pos
{
    public:
        char (&board)[64];
        pos(char (&arr)[64])
            : board(arr)
        {
            *board = *arr;
        }
        void print();
};

void pos::print()
{
    for (int y=0; y<8; y++)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<8; x++)
            std::cout << (int) board[x + y*8] << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    char test[64] = {
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
        2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
        3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,
        4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,
        5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,
        6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,
        7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14 };

    pos p(test);
    p.print();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

But if I change all instances of `pos` to `position`, I get the error: main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall position::print(void)" (?print@position@@QAEXXZ) already defined in position.obj
1>D:\Programming\Test\Debug\Test.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Oddly, the class used to be named `position` and compiled fine until I made some changes to how it handles the `board` array. Can someone explain why I'm getting this error?

**Update**

Now it doesn't matter what the class is named, I get the same error. I created a new MSVC++ project, copied the source files, and did a new build. Same error. Here's the actual code, instead of the concise version.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "position.cpp"

int main()
{
    char test[64] = {               // Simple mate test position; TODO: move to test suite
        OO,BK,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,
        OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,WR,
        OO,WK,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,
        OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,
        OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,
        OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,
        OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,
        OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO,OO };

    position pos(test);
    pos.print();

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

position.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

// Board-centric representation; pass as 64-byte array

#define WK 0x0  // White King   
#define WQ 0x1  // White Queen
#define WR 0x2  // White Rook
#define WB 0x3  // White Bishop
#define WN 0x4  // White Knight
#define WP 0x5  // White Pawn
#define BK 0x6  // Black King
#define BQ 0x7  // Black Queen
#define BR 0x8  // Black Rook
#define BB 0x9  // Black Bishop
#define BN 0xA  // Black Knight
#define BP 0xB  // Black Pawn
// 0xC: unused
// 0xD: unused
// 0xE: unused
#define OO 0xF  // Empty

class position
{
    public:
        char (&board)[64];
        position(char (&arr)[64])   // TODO: 'board' dies if the variable passed through 'arr' dies. Allocating memory might fix this. See 'new' and 'shared_ptr'.
            : board(arr)
        {
            *board = *arr;
        }
        void print();
};

void position::print()
{
    for (int y=0; y<8; y++)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<8; x++)
            std::cout << (int) board[x + y*8] << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

(I'm writing a program to figure out simple chess endgames.)

As you can see, `position::print()` is only defined in one place, contrary to the error message...unless I'm seriously overlooking something. It's pretty early.

Comment: Are you linking against an old obj file where the class used to be named position?  Where did position.obj come from?

Comment: No, `position` is not a keyword. Are you sure you're doing a completely clean build?

Comment: There are no errors with compiling your code with g++ after replacing all `pos` to `position`.

Comment: @Retired Ninja: The `pos` class above used to be called `position`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're compiling the code contained in `position.cpp` *twice*, and you're trying to linking the compiled code into one file.

The problem is caused by this line in `main.cpp`:

```
#include "position.cpp"
```

You're including the C++ source file, not the header. This means that all code in `position.cpp` is included in `main.cpp` and then the resulting file is compiled. You then compile `position.cpp` on it's own.

Try to include `position.h` instead - if there's no such header yet, define it. The alternative fix is to not add `position.cpp` to the list of sources to be compiled.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a novice, so I've yet to learn about header files. Now seems to be the right time. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't `#include "position.cpp"` in your main file, but a header file for the `position` class instead.

Comment: dang, should have posted a shorter answer :D

Comment: I'm too lazy to do it, but I think the OP deserves a better explanation of how translation units work. It's your chance :)

Comment: after a big lunch like I just had I don't think that will happen right now :)

Answer (score 1):

You are including postition.cpp in main.cpp, probably your build system also builds position.cpp separately and then the linker finds multiple definitions of your class.

You should make a separate header and add include guards, `#pragma once` for example on msvc

Comment: Strange that it worked fine until recently... The consensus is definitely to include a header file instead of the cpp file. Thank you for your explanation and advice.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that you have two definitions of `void position::print()`, one in `main.cpp` the other one in `position.cpp`.

Comment: But I don't. Is there another explanation?

Comment: My best guess is that you don't master your build system and you are linking in `position.cpp` even if you think you aren't.

Comment: Oh, I'm linking in `position.cpp` in my original code. But the class and its methods are only defined in one place. The code I gave above was rewritten for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a reserved word, it's a name that **you** used in `position.cpp`. You're using the same name, but with a different meaning in `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler/linker deals in translation units, not files. You may have the definition of position::print in one file (position.cpp). But the definition is actually present in *two* translation units since you wrote `#include "position.cpp"`. You violated the ODR (one definition rule).